# How can I access an entity manager without providing unit name in @PersistenceContext?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have defined multiple persistence units with multiple entity manager factories and multiple transaction managers. 
I know I can access the respective entity manager by providing a unit name to persistence context like this.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="PU1")
protected transient EntityManager entityManager;
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I can access a default persistence unit.

```
@PersistenceContext
protected transient EntityManager entityManager;
```

I want this entity manager to select my persistence unit "PU1" as default.

While defining my PersistenceUnitManager, I defined the defaultDataSource to the one I want but it did not help.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't know which persistence unit to use, try creating a persistence.xml for each persistence unit and choose which one to use in the application context
try this:

```
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistencePU1.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```